# how to change the filename stored on disk - django, s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am trying to change the name of a file that a user uploads. I can get it to change the filename, but it is still stored in the S3 server as the original filename.

Django says that -- "The file is saved as part of saving the model in the database, so the actual file name used on disk cannot be relied on until after the model has been saved."

You guys know of any tips on where do put a function in either my view, form or model to allow for me to change the filename on the disk?

from forms.py:

```
class AddAttachmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = ('attachment',)
        labels = {
            'attachment': ''
        }
        widgets = {
            'attachment': forms.FileInput(attrs={'style':'display:none;'})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.error_messages = {
                'required': '{fieldname} is required'.format(fieldname=field.label),
            }
```

from models.py

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    def rand_str(n): return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(n)])
    random_folder = rand_str(75)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    competency = models.ForeignKey('Competency', related_name="attachments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=random_folder, blank=True)
    attacher = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='attacher', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date_attached = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

from views.py

```
        form = AddAttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            attachment = form.save(commit=False)
            attachment.user = student
            attachment.attacher = self.request.user
            attachment.date_attached = timezone.now()
            attachment.competency = competency
            attachment.filename = request.FILES['attachment'].name
            attachment.save()
```

Comment: Show your `random_folder` function.

Comment: random_folder is just a variable that hold the random string. rand_str is a function and it is shown in models.py. Correct? What am i missing?

Comment: Ah, well it *should* be a function, which will additionally take care of renaming the file for you. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).